# Can we get signing identity of p12 certificate without inserting into keychain

Tags: macos, ssl, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I want to find alternative way for finding identity of a certificate

```
security find-identity -p codesigning
```

By using the above command, i could fetch the list of identities in the keychain, but i want identity of certificate which is not in keychain